# Unclear the swap letters

Tags: prolog

I have something misunderstood in an exercise.It says swap two letters.It has an example women and it is wmoen.It ask me to do it.What i did and it worked

```
swapletters(W,CW):-      // women because is wmoen 
    append(A,[X,Y|B],W),  //it has A because it keeps the w and swap m and o thats why is out of the [ ],B is the tail that keeps en,W is word.
    word(CW),
    append(A,[Y,X|B],CW).
```

My question is if it was another word like eating and it was eatnig.Will it worked this code and for it?I am doing it but i am not sure about it.Thanks

Comment: Why are you asking? Why don't you try more test cases to investigate?

Comment: Make sure you say `:- set_prolog_flag(double_quotes, chars).` so you can  read the actual text.